# Repeating function after variable changes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, loops

I want 4 text elements to appear, one after the other, every time a button is clicked. Here is the code I've used to implement that...

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('.text').css({ 'opacity': '0' });

    function loadText(){
        var textNo = 1;

        function nextText(){    
            $('.text'+textNo).animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 400);
            textNo += 1;
        }

        if (textNo <= 4){
            nextText(); 
        };  
    }   

    setTimeout(loadText, 300);
});
```

I want the `nextText()` function to repeat 4 times, although calling it again doesn't seem to have any effect. Have I missed something obvious here?

You can see it here for a limited time: http://thetally.efinancialnews.com/tallyassets/ceo-survey/index.html

I now realise the problem, partially. When nextText is called there is nothing inside that function to run it again. Can you put a call to a function within a function?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use setInterval method instead of setTimeout method. So replace this:

```
setTimeout(loadText, 300);
```

With this:

```
setInterval(loadText, 300);
```

Comment: That won't stop running it after 4 times. It will keep running it forever (and just not do anything for all but the first 4).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to call function repeatedly and move `textNo` so that its incremented value accessible in subsequent call.

Always cancel function from running repeatedly using [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) once condition is fulfilled

Use

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('.text').css({
        'opacity': '0'
    });

    //Move the variable outside
    var textNo = 1;

    function loadText() {
        function nextText() {
            $('.text' + textNo).animate({
                'opacity': '1'
            }, 400);
            textNo++;
        }
        if (textNo <= 4) {
            nextText();
        } else {
            //Cancels repeated action which was set up using setInterval
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }

    //Calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function. 
    var interval = setInterval(loadText, 300);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this kind of answers the question I was just going to ask. 'does setInterval not just repeat indefinitely?, and is that a problem?'

Answer (score 0):

loadText is not available to setTimeout, it being contained within the "click" function. You can simply move the loadText function outside of the click definition, as below.

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('.text').css({
        'opacity': '0'
    });
    setTimeout(loadText, 300);
});

function loadText() {
    var textNo = 1;

    function nextText() {
        $('.text' + textNo).animate({
            'opacity': '1'
        }, 400);
        textNo += 1;
    }
    if (textNo <= 4) {
        nextText();
    };
}
```

Comment: loadText is available to setTimeout because it is defined within the same function that setTimeout is called

Answer (score 0):

Another version with `setTimeout`, but slighly modified code with no `nextText()` which has been (kind of) replaced by the animation callback. As everyone else already said, move `var textNo = 1;` outside the `loadText()`.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('.text').css({ opacity: 0});
    var textNo = 1, timer;

    function loadText() {
        $('.text' + textNo).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 400, function() {
            if ( textNo++ <= 4) {
                loadText();
            } else {
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }
        });
    }

    timer = setTimeout(loadText, 300);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text text1">t1</div>
<div class="text text2">t2</div>
<div class="text text3">t3</div>
<div class="text text4">t4</div>
<button class="btn">Button</button>
```